# Update one SQL Server table from an other table with last transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server: one is `Pay_Rates` and the other is `Transactions`.

`Pay_Rates` contains all employee's pay data and `transactions` has the history of payments.

I want to update `Last_Balance` from `Transactions` to `Pay_Rates`. Which is paid by last time.

Remember that the `Transactions` table has many entries for each employee and I need only the last entry.

Can I use this method to update this record?

```
UPDATE
    Pay_Rates
SET
    Pay_Rates.Balance = Txn.Balance
FROM
    Pay_Rates PR
INNER JOIN
    Transactions Txn ON PR.AccountNo = Txn.AccountNo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a relational database transactions table have a primary key. So partitioned account wise where use id as order by.

```
-- SQL SERVER
UPDATE Pay_Rates
SET Pay_Rates.Balance = Txn.Balance
FROM Pay_Rates PR
INNER JOIN (SELECT AccountNo
                 , Balance
                 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNo ORDER BY id DESC) row_num
            FROM Transactions) Txn
        ON PR.AccountNo = Txn.AccountNo
       AND Txn.row_num = 1;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a6837fa410a19f6c39907109b91be30

Comment: Hi @AECProduction please check the answer and let me know if any questions.

Comment: Welcome @AECProduction. Thanks for your response. If my answer really help you so please mark it accepted and also useful. When anyone searching related this then s/he can pick my answer without any doubt if it's marked and upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Set the number for each row with `ROW_NUMBER()` and group it by `AccountNo` and sort it order by desc and return row number one.

**Note:** Just sort the data in descending order by date of entry or ID so that the last record is numbered as the first record.

```
UPDATE
    Pay_Rates
SET
    Pay_Rates.Balance = Txn.Balance
FROM
    Pay_Rates PR
INNER JOIN (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNo ORDER BY AccountNo DESC) AS seq FROM Transactions) Txn 
  ON PR.AccountNo = Txn.AccountNo AND Txn.seq = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

easier way and more efficient:

```
UPDATE PR
SET PR.Balance = txn.Balance
FROM Pay_Rates PR
cross apply ( 
     select top 1 Balance from Transactions Txn 
     where PR.AccountNo = Txn.AccountNo
     order by txn.transdate desc
) txn;
```